# Fortran Function explanation

Tags: c#, function, fortran

I have this function in Fortran and i'm trying to recode it in C#

```
C **************************************************************** 
C    FUNCTION   POLY 
C***************************************************************** 
      FUNCTION POLY(N,A,X) 
      DIMENSION A(N) 
C
      POLY    = 0. 
      L       = N 
      DO 1 K  = 1,N 
      POLY    = POLY*X + A(L) 
1     L       = L-1 
      RETURN 
      END 
C*****************************************************************
```

I found out that `DIMENSION A(N)` creates a vector of `N` values, but we already have a variable `A` from the function parameters, does this means that the array values all equal to `A`? If so then what is the use of `A(N)`.
By the way can anyone just explain what does this function do so i can re-implement it in C#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
      FUNCTION POLY(N,A,X)      ! implicitly real (float) function poly(int n,int a,real x)
      DIMENSION A(N)            ! shape A as 1d array of n values in this scope
C                               ! say nothing (blank comment)
      POLY    = 0.              ! initialise return variable to float value 0
      L       = N               ! set L (implicitly integer) to n
      DO 1 K  = 1,N             ! for(int k=1; k<=n; ++k)
      POLY    = POLY*X + A(L)   !    update return variable
1     L       = L-1             !    decrement L
      RETURN                    ! return current value for poly
      END
```

so in c-like syntax:

```
float poly(int n, int a, float x) {
    // redim a(n)
    float result = 0;
    int l = n;
    for(int k=1; k <= n; ++k) {
        result = result*x + a(l);
        --l;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The bit that doesn't translate is redimensioning A as an array. In C you would pass a pointer and use it as an array, and in C++/C# you'd probably pass a vector-like structure with its own length property.

In C#, using a list:

```
float poly(List<float> coeffs, float x) {
    float result = 0;
    for(int i=coeffs.Count-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        result = result*x + coeff[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The commenting of the FORTRAN code is nice, but the C# and Python code you present are incorrect.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: ...in what way?

Comment: In the way that they give the wrong answers. In the C# code you mean `=` rather than `+=`. And you iterate over the coefficients in the wrong order. You want to `coeff[n-1]`, `coeff[n-2]` etc. And the Python code bears no relation to polynomial evalutation. You can fix it by replacing the `+` with a `*` but then it's not Horner's method and it inefficient. It's pretty enough, it just gives the wrong answers. The only code in your answer that is correct is the C pseudo code. I'm sure you can correct it easily enough, but as it stands this answer is down-vote bait.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thanks, I spotted the order mistake after your first comment, but not the +=. Removed the python code because the point was more a sensible way to achieve the result in python, rather than replicate the algorithm, since python has its overheads.

Comment: OK, it was getting hard to do this in comments. I corrected your code properly now.

Comment: shouldn't that be `int *a` and `a[l]`? Or perhaps `float *a` (as it would be implicitly that in the fortran code)?

Comment: Thank you guys, you really helped me a lot, I'm now moving toward [A C# Class for Complex Polynomials - CodeProject®](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19446/A-C-Class-for-Complex-Polynomials) because I found out that I'll be using polynomials in other parts of the code so for the sake of consistency I'll re-implement the entire data processing section

Answer (score 3):

It evaluates a polynomial in `x` of the form:

```
a[1] + a[2]x + a[3]x^2 + ... a[N]x^(N-1)
```

Remember that Fortran uses 1-based array indices and I have followed that convention in this equation.

---

You could write it in C# like this:

```
double EvaluatePolynomial(double[] a, double x)
{
    double result = 0.0;
    int i = a.Length;
    while (i>0)
    {
        i--;
        result = result*x + a[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here we are using 0-based array indexing appropriate to C#. And so this function evalutates a polynomial in `x` of the form:

```
a[0] + a[1]x + a[2]x^2 + ... a[N-1]x^(N-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

*guessing slightly* I think this is specifying that the parameter `A` itself is an array of `N` elements.

So for the C# equivalent you wouldn't need a separate `N` parameter; you would only need to pass `A` as a `double[]`, as in .NET arrays can tell you their `.Length`.

The function evaluates polynomials using [Horner's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

Answer (score 2):

The line `DIMENSION A(N)` just declares details of the A dummy argument (`PARAMETERs` are something very different in Fortran), i.e. it says it is an array from 1 to N. The other ones are not declared this way, because the function uses implicit typing.

Comment: Yes.  It is not creating the variable A, it is declaring that dummy argument to describe the actual argument that is being passed to this function.  If the calling routine hasn't created the storage there is a problem.

Comment: It's pretty much equivalent to K&R prototypes in C